# Extract ROIs - Machine learning - References

Tags: image-processing, image, machine-learning, reference-request

I want to try to extract ROIs from certain images using *machine learning and neural networks* , granted I know nothing about this field and it may not be the best way to do this, but the goal is to compare machine learning based algorithms *with other algortihms I have already built*.

Here are the type of images I want to work on :
[image]

Here are the kind of results I want to get from the algorithm :[image]

Do you have any key words, references, resources  on *neural networks and machine learning* or even premade algorithms to help me start in this endeavour ? (Even better if they are related to Mathematica).

I am looking for tutorials and hands-on approaches, not for long abstract or theoretical considerations.

Thank you.

Comment: These seems quite tractable as there appears to be a brightness difference.  The tutorial videos: https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/introduction-to-image-processing/ should put you on the right track

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example:

```
(*imports image above*)
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqtp0.jpg"]; 
(*uses erosion to reduce noise, binarizes to black and white, then dilates to expand*)
binarized = Dilation[#, 5] &@Binarize@Erosion[img, 5]; 
(*identify components; this is one of many possible functions*)
components = ImageForestingComponents[binarized];

(*show the identified components*)
HighlightImage[img, components]
```

[image: example image show identified components]

The results of the various component functions is a 2d-array, whose entries identify which component is where (the first row is `components[[1]]`)

One way to use this is to construct the convex hull containing a set of points.  For example, let's look at region 6

```
hull6 = ConvexHullMesh@Position[components, 6]
```

[image: convex hull mesh of 6]

Where's Waldo?

```
HighlightImage[img, hull6]
```

[image: image with highlighted region 6 convex hull mesh]

Now that we have defined a region, many geometric properties can be assessed, for example,

```
Area[hull6]. (*1490*)
```

For more information, see the Wolfram tutorial video: https://wolfram.com/wolfram-u/introduction-to-image-processing

The image processing guide also contains many helpful examples:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageProcessing.html

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, but I am familiar with this kind of image processing, I am really looking for  neural network based ROI recognition. Helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Your post does *not* make that clear. Please rewrite it so that it is emphasized for potential answer writers.